# Panning via normal vector and plane

Tags: math

I have got a camera and the direction it is looking at. Therefore I can create a plane out of this direction vector if I take it as a normal vector. So now I want to move my camera which should be on this plane along the plane. Everything's in 3D but I couldn't come up with an idea how to do so. How can I implement the navigational method of panning - so moving in this specific plane? 
[image]

Comment: Just make clear what is your query. It is not clear.

Comment: You need to know Up axis as well. Otherwise how would you know left and right directions?

Comment: If you have the vectors that span your plane, you can use them as a basis and every new vector made with this basis will be on the plane

Comment: @Yola up axis from what?

Comment: @user8408080 but how do I know where I move my camera on ? I mean like I somehow have to know where's left and right .. maybe that's the thing Yola mentioned with the up axis.

Comment: @Shudipta Sharma I want to implement panning in a 3D scene. My assumption was to move the camera on the plane i get from the direction it is looking at and in which the camera itself is. But for the further steps I don't know the maths to move the camera exactly on the plane i get .. hope it helped for understanding my issue.

Answer (score 2):

To pan your camera to the left and to the right you need to know not only lookAt direction, but also up direction for the camera. Then you can calculate cross product of lookAt and upAxis and this gives you direction to the right, negated vector gives you direction to the left.

[image]

Comment: hey, i tried it out now and it works great, thank you very much!

Comment: but i wanted to know whether there is a possibility to actually do panning without being dependent to the lookat vector? is it possible?

Comment: maybe using the "straight line" the camera's directed at instead of a specific looking point.

Comment: @user9268398 no, you can't calculate from just up-vector. You see, if you have only up-vector your left and right vectors could point in many directions. Glad it was useful, now you can accept it and also upvote if you like.

Answer (score 0):

**Definition:** A vector `N` that is orthogonal to every vector in a plane is called a **normal** vector to the plane.
[image]

An equation of the plane containing the point `(x0, y0, z0)` with normal vector `N = (A, B, C)`, is `A(x − x0) + B(y − y0) + C(z − z0) = 0`.

> Note: The equation of any plane can be expressed as `Ax + By + Cz = D`.

This is called the **standard form** of the equation of a plane. From the eqn you can get any other point you want on the plane.

**Example:** A plane passing through the point `P = (1, 6, 4)` and the normal vector, `R = (2, - 3, - 1)`. Then the eqn is,

```
   2(x-1) - 3(y-6) - (z-4) = 0
=> 2x - 3y - z = -20
```

Comment: I think it gives you at least some help